# How to add an ActionListener to a button in a frame in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm trying to test out buttons but I can't get an Action Listener to work

```
public class ButtonTester implements ActionListener {

static JLabel Label = new JLabel("Hello Buttons! Will You Work?!");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Creating a Label for step 3
    // now for buttons
    JButton Button1 = new JButton("Test if Button Worked");
    // step 1: create the frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("FrameDemo");
    //step 2: set frame behaviors (close buttons and stuff)
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //step 3: create labels to put in the frame
    frame.getContentPane().add(Label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Button1, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
    //step 4: Size the frame
    frame.pack();
    //step 5: show the frame 
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Button1.setActionCommand("Test");
    Button1.setEnabled(true);
    Button1.addActionListener(this); //this line here won't work
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if("Test".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
    {
        Label.setText("It Worked!!!");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You should create your Swing components on the Swing event thread, using SwingUtilities.invokeLater() in main(). Having ButtonTester implement Runnable, moving the code from main() into run(), then doing SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ButtonTester()) from main() will solve a number of issues at once.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 3):

`this` has no context in a `static` method

Instead, try using something like `Button1.addActionListener(new ButtonTester());` instead...

**Updated**

You may also want to take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) as Swing has some particular requirements...

Answer (score 3):

Static methods are not associated with an instance of a class, and therefore `this` cannot be used.

You could move all your code from main to a non-static method of ButtonTester (say, `run()`, for example) and do something like this from main:

```
new ButtonTester().run();
```

You could also use an anonymous inner class for the ActionListener:

```
Button1.addActionLister(new ActionListener() {
    @Override public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        // ... 
    }
});
```

Comment: Agree, don't like to linger in the `main` method.  Also forgot to mention about initial threads

Comment: Even a regular inner class might be good if you want to change or access properties of the button and want more accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

java says that you can't access a non-static entity from static context(this refers to an object which is non static and main() is static),so we use constructors for initialization:

```
public class ButtonTester implements ActionListener {
static JLabel Label = new JLabel("Hello Buttons! Will You Work?!");
ButtonTester()  //constructor
{
 //Creating a Label for step 3
    // now for buttons
    JButton Button1 = new JButton("Test if Button Worked");
    // step 1: create the frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("FrameDemo");
    //step 2: set frame behaviors (close buttons and stuff)
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //step 3: create labels to put in the frame
    frame.getContentPane().add(Label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Button1, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
    //step 4: Size the frame
    frame.pack();
    //step 5: show the frame 
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Button1.setActionCommand("Test");
    Button1.setEnabled(true);
    Button1.addActionListener(this); //this line here won't work
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
ButtonTester test1=new ButtonTester();// constructor will be invoked and new object created


}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if("Test".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
    {
        Label.setText("It Worked!!!");
    }
  }
}
```